# My threads stop after a few hours of running

Tags: java, multithreading, multiprocessing

I need to run some bash commands that each of them takes about 18 hrs to finish. In order to use all the available CPU cores I ran each command on a separate thread using the following code. However, the threads stop doing anything after about 5 hrs of working. I know that by checking the cpu usage. When I run only one command using the same code it runs fine. Also I ran several commands in different bash terminal sessions to make sure they are really independent.

```
public class RunBashCommand implements Runnable{
    private String[] command; // e.g. {"bash", "myScript.sh", "arg1", arg2"} 
    private String fSSubjectFolder; 
    private String subjectId;


    RunBashCommand ( String[] newCommand, String newSubjectFolder, String newSubjectId ) {
        command = newCommand;
        fSSubjectFolder = newSubjectFolder;
        subjectId = newSubjectId;

    }

    public void run ( ){
        runCommand ();
    }

    private void runCommand (){
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p;
        try {
            String line;
            p = run.exec(command);
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream() ) );
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter( new File( fSSubjectFolder+"/"+subjectId+"CTPFS.log" ) );
            while ( ( line = buf.readLine() ) != null ){
                pw.println( line );
            }
            p.waitFor();
            pw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and in the parent thread, that invokes this class, I have:

```
while (commandList.size()>0) {
   String[] command = commandList.get(commandList.size()-1); // FILO queue
   Runnable runBash = new RunBashCommand( command, "folderAddress1", "folderAddress2" );
   Thread runBashThread = new Thread ( runBash );
   runBashThread.setName ( "some name" );
   runBashThread.start();
   RunCTPFS.threads.add(runBashThread); // my thread list for thread tracking
   commandList.remove(commandList.size()-1);
}
```

Any help would be most appreciated. I am suspicious of starvation.

Comment: have you tried leaving an open thread for "oh s**t"? Reason I say that is maybe utilizing all open threads, there is some sort of an emergency procedure on the OS level that stops/pauses the process to execute, and the process can't restart. So leaving an open thread may allow thios process to run without interrupting anything

Comment: @user60812 I don't know what you're saying. None of that... makes sense...

Comment: What do you mean by leaving an open thread? The main thread runs so many other threads beside this one. Those threads remain active all the time. For example there is a thread that updates my database every 10 minutes and that works fine even after 20 hrs of running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Does your bash script produce any output on stderr? It looks like you're reading its stdout via `getInputStream()` but you're not doing anything with `getErrorStream()`. If you don't read stderr then  the process could hang if its stderr buffer fills up.

   Best practice when invoking processes is to read both stdout and stderr in separate threads. You must read them in parallel threads to avoid blocking.
2. You don't need to have separate Java threads just for `exec()`. Each `exec()` call will start a separate process which executes in a separate thread of execution. The separate Java threads don't buy you anything. You can do all of the `exec()` calls from a single thread.

My recommendation: start all of the processes from a single thread. For each `Process` object you receive, start two background threads: one to process stdout, one to process stderr. Then in the original thread you can do `waitFor()` on each process in a loop.

```
List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<>();

for (String command: commands) {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    (new BackgroundReaderThread(process.getInputStream())).start();
    (new BackgroundReaderThread(process.getErrorStream())).start();

    processes.add(process);
}

for (Process process: processes) {
    process.waitFor();
}
```